# C# from db to treeview menu creation

Tags: c#, foreach, treeview, dataset, dataadapter

I aim to create treeview menu with using dt ,ds and geting data from DB tables. My code like down below. Got error at Ds  I mark it inside code you can see.. it gives an error  " Incorrect Systax near 'İşlemleri' " ,  İşlemleri  is part of value that tnParent.Text contains. ( Gişe İşlemleri)

```
  void fill_Tree2()
  {

     DataSet PrSet = PDataset("select * from mnu_tbl_mnuElmnlr");

     treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

     foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
     {

        TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();

        tnParent.Text = dr["MenuAdi"].ToString();  /////////////////// 'Gişe İşlemleri' 
        tnParent.Tag = dr["id"].ToString(); 


        tnParent.Expand();

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent);

        FillChild(tnParent, tnParent.Text);

     }

  }

  public void FillChild(TreeNode parent, string ParentId)
  {

     DataSet ds = PDataset("Select altMenuAdi from mnu_tbl_AltElmnlr where ustMenuId = (select id from mnu_tbl_mnuElmnlr)); 

     parent.Nodes.Clear();

     foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
     {

        TreeNode child = new TreeNode();

        child.Text = dr["altMenuAdi"].ToString();       

        //  child.Tag = dr["ChildId"].ToString().Trim();

        parent.Nodes.Add(child);

     }

  }


  protected DataSet PDataset(string Select_Statement)
  {

     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

     //   conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["1123"].ConnectionString;

     SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection("server=123;Database=123;Trusted_Connection=True;");

     SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(Select_Statement, SqlCon);

     DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     ad.Fill(ds);  /////// Here it gives an error  " Incorrect Systax near 'İşlemleri' "

     return ds;


  }
```

Comment: What data type is ustMenuId ?

Comment: ustMenuId type is Int at db

Comment: Have you tried to run the query to the sql server directly?

Comment: I change query with this but this time it says   
"Select altMenuAdi from mnu_tbl_AltElmnlr where ustMenuId = (select id from mnu_tbl_mnuElmnlr)" Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: select top 1  id from mnu_tbl_mnuElmnlr but have you more than one values with the same id?

Comment: yes got more than 1 values , without subquery I insert manual value for that query and I can see that its working .Select altMenuAdi from mnu_tbl_AltElmnlr where ustMenuId = 1"  Problem based on subquery .

Comment: so use the previous post (select top 1 id from mnu_tbl_mnuElmnlr)

Comment: Select altMenuAdi from mnu_tbl_AltElmnlr where ustMenuId = (select top 1 id from mnu_tbl_mnuElmnlr)  query gives only 1 row I need to check all values and find that rows that got same id number.